# Use .new or .create! when testing Rails models with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I have a Contacts table in a Rails 3.1 app. I want last_name to accept 40 characters, so in my model I wrote `:length => { :maximum => 40 }`. However a typo in my migration created the last_name column with `:limit => 30`.

I wondered why my Rspec test hadn't caught this:

```
it "should allow last_name up to max length" do
  long_field = "a" * 40
  Contact.new(@attr.merge(:last_name => long_field)).should be_valid
end
```

then I realized that's only checking the model.  If I use `.create!` instead, the test fails nicely:

```
it "should allow last_name up to max length" do
  long_field = "a" * 40
  Contact.create!(@attr.merge(:last_name => long_field)).should be_valid
end
```

So the question is, should I always use `.create!` when testing my models? Or is that too slow?  How else can I make sure that my model and DB definitions don't conflict?

This also has me wondering if I should just leave strings as 255 in the database and only check the length in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use .new as much as possible for speed reasons.  And to make your test fail you should use validates_length_of.  As for the string length, ideally they should match and if you are feeling excessively thorough you could [reflect on validations](http://markconnell.co.uk/posts/2010/02/rails-3-validation-reflection) and Model.columns to verify that you have validation for each column.

Comment: Finally getting back to the details on this one. I'm using `:validates :length` instead of `:validates_length_of`, but either one lets the test pass if the rspec test uses `:new`.  In other words, if the model validator is correct but the DB field is too short, the `:new` test passes because it doesn't write to the database.  I don't think reflection would help because it's also not checking the database. Seems odd that migration <-> model synchronization is a manual process. So far, `:create!` is the only way I see to test that the DB accepts what the model will give it.